# how to parsing .net Dataset returned by web service to android

Tags: android, web-services

i have a dataset returned by .net webservice and i want to parse this and obtain any object (array, list, hashtable... any, i don't mind) to work on android

Dataset contains 19 tables with multiple rows.

Edited:

when i do

```
String a = (String) response.getProperty(1).toString();
  //getProperty(0) = dataset schema
  //getProperty(1) = dataset data
```

when I get the string, i don't get a xml, but more like:

```
anyType{NewDataSet=anyType{
 delegaciones=anyType{nombredelegacion=ALMERY\SIGALMERY                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 ; coddelegacion=AL1; sede=NO; delegacion=ALMERY\SIGALMERY2
 ; rowguid=7acac29f-fb36-424c-bbf0-05c03; nombrecomun=ALMERY  
  ... etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In webService: return dataset.getXML(); and try to parse the returned xml with XAP.

This is a good example:

http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/?p=1542

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there are no DataSet wrappers in java, so you'll probably have to parse it yourself with one of the available **[Xml parsers.](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/package-summary.html)**